# Why isn't the "Add a job" link coming on the index.html.erb page?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, erb, missing-features

I have been following a tutorial and ended up with this so far : https://github.com/ScarletMcLearn/jobsboard

but a "Add a job" link is supposed to appear on the index.html page as written in the index.html.erb file :

```
<h1>Jobs</h1>
<% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <div class="job">
    <h2><%= link_to job.title, job.url %></h2>
    <p><%= job.company %></p>
  </div>
<% end %>
<p><%= link_to "Add a job", new_job_path %></p>
```

But its not coming. 
I'm new at Rails, so simple instructions will be appreciated. :D
Do check out the Repo : https://github.com/ScarletMcLearn/jobsboard if it helps.

Thanks for the read. :D

rake routes output:

> Prefix Verb   URI Pattern              Controller#Action
>       jobs GET    /jobs(.:format)          jobs#index
>            POST   /jobs(.:format)          jobs#create  new_job GET    /jobs/new(.:format)      jobs#new edit_job GET
>   /jobs/:id/edit(.:format) jobs#edit
>        job GET    /jobs/:id(.:format)      jobs#show
>            PATCH  /jobs/:id(.:format)      jobs#update
>            PUT    /jobs/:id(.:format)      jobs#update
>            DELETE /jobs/:id(.:format)      jobs#destroy
>       root GET    /                        jobs#index

Comment: @luissimo what say mate? :D

Comment: looks like it should work.  maybe try restarting your server or refreshing your browser

Comment: @TomL i use port 4000. I did it. But still no change. :(

Comment: Are you certain that your code looks like this? It looks good honestly... Double check routes (i.e. `rake routes`) to make sure `new_job_path` exists, double check that your link is not within the loop, otherwise try creating a non related link (e.g. `<%= link_to "Nothing", "#" %>`) and see if this shows up. Any other link issues in the app?

Comment: I poked around in your repo and it looks good to me as well :/ if you could `rake routes` and put the new_job_path output in your question that might be helpful.

Comment: @jaydel did it mate -in the edit- :) do update.

Comment: @fbelanger No :D only this confirmation link doesn't come :( do update

Comment: @ScarletMcLearn did you try making another link beside this one? It is not a confirmation link...